# Should I use have or has?

Tags: grammar

Should I use '*have*' or '*has*' for the following sentence?

> I hope you and your class **has** a great day.
>
> I hope you and your class **have** a great day.

Answer (score 1):

> I hope you and your class **have** a great day.

Use "have" as it is, in your sentence, *you* and *your class* which refers to your classmates implicitly.

Thus, you have two entities that the main verb (have) refers to, they are:

- one individual which are **you**
- and a group of people which are **your class**